# PHP Deployer: How to get user name from host setup

Tags: php-deployer

I am trying to deploy my code via php deployer, but I am facing a syntax issue, which is how can I re-use the `host user` on `task`?

For instance, I would like to replace `USERNAME` with `barfoo` in dynamic way. Not hard code.

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Much appropriate.

```
host('17.99.88.225')
     ->user('barfoo') // This is the server user name
     ->stage('production')
     ->set('deploy_path', '/SERVER_PATH/{{application}}')
     ->set('branch', 'develop');

...

task('upload:env', function () {
      runLocally('scp .env USERNAME@{{hostname}}:{{release_path}}/.env');
})->desc('Environment setup');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out myself. I would like to share here:

All I need to do is set a new variable and use it on my script. LOL

```
set('username', 'nanomed1'); // set my own variable
...
task('upload:env', function () {

  $username = get( 'username');  // use the variable I created on the top

  runLocally('scp .env '.$username.'@{{hostname}}:{{release_path}}/.env');
})->desc('Environment setup');
```

That's it!